# When/While I talked to him, my other friends drank beer - differences?

Tags: meaning, conjunctions

**Example 1**

> When I was talking to him, my other friends were drinking beer.

**Example 2**

> When I talked to him, my other friends drank beer.

**Example 3**

> While I talked to him, my other friends drank beer.

Does Example 2 mean the same as Example 1?

Does Example 3 mean the same as Example 1?

In my view, Example 2 sounds like I am talking about a repeated thing in the past, not a single event like Example 1.

Comment: You are right. Examples 1 and 3 relate to a specific instance in the  past "X and Y happened at the same time", whereas Example 2 is "whenever X happened, Y also happened".

Comment: I would use (1) but with _while_ instead of _when_.

Answer (score 0):

Examples 1 and 3 have the same meaning.

"When", in the context of sentence 2 can be understood in two different ways.

One meaning is "*the one time that*", which means I talked to him once, and when I did my friends drank beer instead.

The other meaning of "when" here is "*every time that*", which has a similar meaning to the first interpretation, except that it happened repeatedly -- every time that I talked to him, my friends drank beer.